# MySQL Delete-Select row

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row from table *subscription* where there is two foreign Keys (*id_user* and *id_journal*). The information that I have is *email* from table *user* and *nome* from table *journal*. The deleted row needs to match *user.email* and *journal.nome*. I can't find a solution. How can I do it?

Table user:

```
id
name
email
password
```

Table journal:

```
id
name
```

Table Subscription:

```
id
id_user
id_journal
```

The last two queries that I tried:

```
DELETE FROM assinatura WHERE (
SELECT  tbluser.id, journal.id
FROM    tbluser, journal
WHERE email = '$email' AND nome = '$nome')

DELETE FROM assinatura 
INNER JOIN tbluser on (tbluser.email = '$email')
INNER JOIN journal on (journal.nome = '$nome')
```

I've tried many others queries, but unsuccessful. I think it's important to say that I'm new at MySQL.

Comment: what is the query you tried?

Comment: Let me know if I explained bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM Subscription
WHERE id_user IN (
   SELECT      usr.id 
   FROM        user AS usr 
   WHERE       usr.email = INPUT_EMAIL
) 
AND id_journal IN (
   SELECT      jrnl.id 
   FROM        journal AS jrnl 
   WHERE       jrnl.name = INPUT_NAME
)
```

Comment: Don't think that will help

Comment: The ,id values are not related. The user name is prob not "People Magazine "

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But. ON use.name = jrnl.name? Is that right? I'll try it.

Comment: It's ok. I'm using a test DB.

Comment: You can do it simpler without correlated subqueries tho

Comment: Thanks AsConfused for debugging.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Akadisoft and AsConfused for your help. It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

On another topic ...

Try to avoid excess subscriptions for same user/journal combo by

```
CREATE TABLE subscription
(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  id_user int not null,
  id_journal int not null,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_journal_intersect` (`id_user`,`id_journal`)
  -- note Alan stated FK RI in place already
);
```

U can PK on composite instead, of course (ditching the `id` column), programmer pref

Comment: I'm already controlling user/journal subscription in Java. Anyway, I don't understand intersect use. Can u explain for me, please?

Comment: Oh what u have with subscription table is what ya call an intersect table in programming. Call the index name anything u want or nothing at all and it will give it a name

Comment: The other thing is this has the DB enforce it and protect u

Comment: A progr could say he is controlling the FK in java. But in your case you are entrusting the DB to protect u. Same concept

Comment: I'll read more about intersects. Thank you. Akadisoft reply with your help worked. Thank you so much. I've spent many hours trying it.

Comment: U are already implementing an intersect by your subscription table don't read up on it !

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm learning yet. Something that I do maybe I don't know the correct names. Thx.